# different global state on a component react redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, state

I am using react and redux.

I have a component that has an input. When writing on this input, a function is executed:

```
<input value={code} onChange={(e) => check(e.target.value)} ></input>
```

**check()** function:

```
const check = (code) => {
    dispatch(getCodeInfo({ code: code }));
}
```

Then I get the codeInfo from the state with the useSelector():

```
const codeInfo = useSelector((state) => state.codeInfo);
  const {
    loading,
    error,
    code,
    success,
  } = codeInfo;
```

And finally I display a message in case of an error:

```
{error && <MessageBox>{error}</MessageBox>}
```

The problem is that I have this component many times on the same screen, and the message is displayed on all of them when it should only be in the one that the input has been written on.
I know this is happening because "**const codeInfo = useSelector((state) => state.codeInfo)**" is bringing the codeInfo on all the component's instances, since it is like a global state, but I have no clue on how to fix this

Any idea would be really appreciated

Comment: That is because ***it is*** a global state, and there's only one of them driving all the inputs. You'll want to store an object of the input states by some identifier so they can be uniquely keyed. Or look into a library that does this for you like [redux-form](https://redux-form.com/8.3.0/) if you think you need to store the form data in redux. There are many react form solutions out there.

Comment: If you don't want global state then use local state with [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) and run [an effect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) when input changes.

Comment: got it, thank you! @DrewReese

Comment: thank you too! @HMR